# checking if kinect is connected or not

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, kinect

I am creating a WPF/C# app that uses the kinect for moving objects but it also runs with using the mouse. Currently I comment out the kinect code for it work using the mouse. I need way to recognize whether the kinect is connected or not so I don't have to comment out code for it to use the mouse when it's not (without throwing an exception as it currently does) and use kinect when it does.
How may I do that?? 
info: I am using official Microsoft Kinect SDKs (Downloaded about a week ago)

Edit--
I am using these

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using GridAnimationDemo;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Research.Kinect.Nui;
using Microsoft.Research.Kinect.Audio;
using Microsoft.Research.Kinect;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using System.Windows.Data;
using Microsoft.Research.Kinect.Samples.CursorControl;
using Coding4Fun.Kinect.Wpf;
using Coding4Fun;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
```

Cannot add reference and use Microsoft.Kinect as it creates conflicts with some of these

EDIT--

```
Device dvc = new Device();
            if (dvc.Count.Equals(0))
                MessageBox.Show("apoellin");
```

I tried the above code and the app crashes with the same error it crashes if I use any Kinect code with Kinect not connected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a very out of date version of the Kinect for Windows SDK.  The `Microsoft.Research.Kinect` namespace is from the beta.

The latest SDK can be downloaded here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/developer-downloads.aspx

After you do that, download the Developer Toolkit, also available from the link above.  It contains multiple examples of how to do many tasks.

I strongly suggest looking at the Kinect Explorer example.  This will show you how to use a data container called KinectSensorManager.  This class is a data wrapper and not part of the SDK -- it helps manage the Kinect sensor.  It is included in several of the Toolkit examples.

The class, among other things, fires events when the Kinect sensor state changes.  So you can set your program up to initialize and uninitialized the Kinect in the appropriate event handlers.

Comment: I have 45 A4 pages of code based on that SDK..... changing as it seems is not an option because a lot of stuff don't work

Comment: Well, I guess that is up to you.  You're using an SDK that is very out of date, is lacking many features and will be incompatable with a large swath of libraries that exist now and in the future.  You are going to find a lot less help for your questions with such an old SDK - folks don't have it to test against.  Also, a large portion of what you have to work for in the old SDK comes for free (or a lot less effort) in the new SDK.  You'll need to switch over eventually, might as well be now.

Comment: Well the fact is this project is semester project for HCI lesson. I am given this code and I must alter it to do some extra tasks. Somehow I must add this task aswell

Comment: I'd go for the extra credit and impress your instructor by upgrading it to the latest SDK as well. :)

Comment: 45 pages of code to be altered to match new SDK??? too much extra credit :P I'll see what I can do

Comment: what event does kinect throw when it is connected?

Comment: `KinectSensor.KinectSensors.StatusChanged` will capture events when a Kinect and connected or disconnected.

Answer (score 5):

Here is code from the book "Beginning Kinect Programming with the Microsoft SDK", which handles this nicely

```
// (in your page/window constructor):

this.KinectDevice = KinectSensor.KinectSensors
.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Status == KinectStatus.Connected);

// (and create a property like this:)

public KinectSensor KinectDevice
{
get { return this._KinectDevice; }
set
{
if (this._KinectDevice != value)
{
//Uninitialize
if (this._KinectDevice != null)
{
this._KinectDevice.Stop();
this._KinectDevice.SkeletonFrameReady -= KinectDevice_SkeletonFrameReady;
this._KinectDevice.SkeletonStream.Disable();
this._FrameSkeletons = null;
}

this._KinectDevice = value;

//Initialize
if (this._KinectDevice != null)
{
if (this._KinectDevice.Status == KinectStatus.Connected)
{
this._KinectDevice.SkeletonStream.Enable();
this._FrameSkeletons = new
Skeleton[this._KinectDevice.SkeletonStream.FrameSkeletonArrayLength];
this.KinectDevice.SkeletonFrameReady +=
KinectDevice_SkeletonFrameReady;
ColorImageStream colorStream = this._KinectDevice.ColorStream;
colorStream.Enable();
this._ColorImageBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(colorStream.FrameWidth,
colorStream.FrameHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
this._ColorImageBitmapRect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, colorStream.FrameWidth,
colorStream.FrameHeight);
this._ColorImageStride = colorStream.FrameWidth * colorStream.FrameBytesPerPixel;
ColorImageElement.Source = this._ColorImageBitmap;
this._KinectDevice.ColorFrameReady += Kinect_ColorFrameReady;

this.ColorImageElement.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
this._ColorImageBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(colorStream.FrameWidth,
colorStream.FrameHeight,
96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32,
null);
this._ColorImageBitmapRect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, colorStream.FrameWidth,
colorStream.FrameHeight);
this._ColorImageStride = colorStream.FrameWidth *
colorStream.FrameBytesPerPixel;
this._ColorImagePixelData = new byte[colorStream.FramePixelDataLength];

this.ColorImageElement.Source = this._ColorImageBitmap;
}));
this._KinectDevice.Start();
}
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the latest Windows SDK, you can check for value of `Runtime.Kinects.Count`.

If value is 0 then no Kinects are connected -

```
if (Runtime.Kinects.Count == 0)
{
    // No Kinects are connected
}
else
{
    // Kinect is connecetd
}
```

Comment: I get this error
'Microsoft.Research.Kinect.Nui.Runtime' does not contain a definition for 'Kinects'

I have the latest Kinect sdk and toolkit

Comment: @macrian - I assure you that Microsoft.Kintect namespace has a Kintects class.  Be specific use the full namespace to the class.

Comment: @macrian - You are going to have to point out what change in your question, my statement is still valid, the `Kinects` does exist so it must be a problem how your importing the namespace.

Comment: I cannot use Microsoft.Kinect as it creates conflicts with some of the others that I am using. For Kinect I am using Microsoft.Research.Kinect

Comment: @macrian, see my answer below.  `Microsoft.Kinect` is causing problems because you have references to a very old version of the Kinect SDK.  You need to remove the old version and update your references (which will be `Microsoft.Kinect`.

Comment: and this will not need any changes in my code? all the code I have in my app will still work with the newest version of the SDK??

Comment: What about Microsoft.Research.Nui and audio etc?? what shall I do with them?? If i remove Microsoft.research.kinect they don't work

Comment: All this namespaces have been rolled into one.  No, your code is not going to just work after you upgrade.  You will have to do some work to port it over.  But if you are *just learning* why would you want to learn on something so *old*!?  As I mention below, you will get much less help on such an old SDK, because we don't use it anymore!

Answer (score 2):

I'd just like to add an answer for the Kinect 2.0 SDK. Unfortunately the SDK no longer has the `Runtime` namespace or any other ways for listing devices. However you can use WMI to determine if a Kinect 2.0 is connected.

For this to work you need to add a references to the System.Management library.

```
public static bool IsConnected()
{            
    // Use WMI to find devices with the proper hardware id for the Kinect2
    // note that one Kinect2 is listed as three harwdare devices    
    string query = String.Format(WmiQuery, HardwareId);
    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
    {
        using (var collection = searcher.Get())
        {
            return collection.Count > 0;
        }
    }            
}

private const string HardwareId = @"VID_045E&PID_02C4";
private const string WmiQuery = @"SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE DeviceID LIKE '%{0}%'";
```

Update, since Microsoft discontinued its Kinect 2 for Windows, and now uses the Xbox One's Kinect for Windows, we have discovered not all Kinect 2's use the same ID. At the moment we use these Ids. This seems to work.

```
<!-- Kinect 2 For Xbox -->
USB\VID_045E&PID_02C4
<!-- Kinect 2 For Windows -->
USB\VID_045E&PID_02D9
```

Comment: Do the hardware IDs change by SDK release?  I had to use VID_045E&PID_02D8 to find mine.

Comment: So far I found out that the Xbox and WIndows versions have slightly different Ids, and there are at least 3 separate devices which represent the Kinect as a whole. All of those have their own id's. I wish there was a cleaner way to detect it. I do not understand why this 'feature' was removed.