# how to ignore an exception

Tags: c#, exception, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am writing a kinect app in C# and I have this code

```
try             //start of kinect code
{
    _nui = new Runtime();
    _nui.Initialize(RuntimeOptions.UseSkeletalTracking | RuntimeOptions.UseDepthAndPlayerIndex | RuntimeOptions.UseColor);

    // hook up our events for video
    _nui.DepthFrameReady += _nui_DepthFrameReady;
    _nui.VideoFrameReady += _nui_VideoFrameReady;

    // hook up our events for skeleton
    _nui.SkeletonFrameReady += new EventHandler<SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs>(_nui_SkeletonFrameReady);

    // open the video stream at the proper resolution
    _nui.DepthStream.Open(ImageStreamType.Depth, 2, ImageResolution.Resolution320x240, ImageType.DepthAndPlayerIndex);
    _nui.VideoStream.Open(ImageStreamType.Video, 2, ImageResolution.Resolution640x480, ImageType.Color);

    // parameters used to smooth the skeleton data
    _nui.SkeletonEngine.TransformSmooth = true;
    TransformSmoothParameters parameters = new TransformSmoothParameters();
    parameters.Smoothing = 0.8f;
    parameters.Correction = 0.2f;
    parameters.Prediction = 0.2f;
    parameters.JitterRadius = 0.07f;
    parameters.MaxDeviationRadius = 0.4f;
    _nui.SkeletonEngine.SmoothParameters = parameters;

    //set camera angle
    _nui.NuiCamera.ElevationAngle = 17;
}
catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Could not initialize Kinect device.\nExiting application.");
    _nui = null;

}
```

I am looking for a way for my app to not crash (the exception to be ignored) when kinect is not connected. I created another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360443/checking-if-kinect-is-connected-or-not) but the solutions could not be applied to my occasion as I am forced to use outdated sdk and nobody can solve that quesiton so I am trying to use a different approach. How can I ignore this exception? (I can reverse the changes made to _nui myself afterwards)

Comment: What exception is being thrown that you want to ignore? at a glance the code above looks like it should ignore any `COMException` thrown in that code block but there is nothing to say that a null reference exception might not be thrown later if _nui is accessed elsewhere.

Comment: It really depends on what the exception is. You can only "ignore" exceptions that are not vital to your code logic.

Comment: the whole _nui point AFTER this part of code can be handled by me (I already thought of how) the point is I need my app to get pass this part of the code, no matter what I put in the catch brackets the app keeps on crashing(throwing exception) right there

Comment: @macrian, what exception? ComException?

Comment: If I am reading it correctly yes
Is there a way for me to know exactly the position where the exception was thrown without breakpoints?

Comment: @macrian please post your stack trace

Comment: the stack trace shows > [External Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're catching all of ComExceptions. If you want to catch other exceptions, you need to provide specific types for each exception.

You can add your exception types after your catch block like this:

```
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Could not initialize Kinect device.\nExiting application.");
        _nui = null;

    } catch (Exception ex) //this will catch generic exceptions.
    {

    }
```

If you want your code to execute after catch No matter what. you can also try to use [finally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

like this

```
try
{
  //logic
}
finally
{
  //logic. This will be executed and then the exception will be catched
}
```

Comment: don't work and I have no idea why. It's a System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
Is there a way to find out exactly where the exception is thrown? maybe this happens somewhere else than this code. How can I find that out??

Comment: @macrian, well you can look at your stack trace to see where exactly it was thrown or try debugging in Visual studio

Comment: I tried but I don't seem to understand it.... I apologize if I am too much of a noob

Comment: @macrian, Can you please follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945193/how-do-i-find-the-stack-trace-in-visual-studio and post stack trace as an edit to your post?

Comment: > [External Code] 
this is what's included inside the call stack

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to ignore all exceptions:

```
try 
{
// your code... 
} 
catch (Exception E)
{ 
// whatever you need to do...
};
```

The above is a catch-all (although some exception can't be caught like Stackoverflow).

**REMARK**

**You should NOT use the above... you should find out what sort of exception is thrown and catch that!**

Comment: don't work and I have no idea why. It's a System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
Is there a way to find out exactly where the exception is thrown? maybe this happens somewhere else than this code. How can I find that out??

Comment: @macrian You can tell the visual studio debugger to break when an exception is thrown; this can make some sorts of exception-throwing async operations much easier to deal with. It might not help you in this particular case, of course. Have a look at the "Exceptions..." option under the "Debug" menu.